Material raised button is getting cut when placed inside a list
Material raised button is being cut when placed inside a list. How to fix this issue?
When I override the mdc-list-item__content class in the browser, I am able to make it look properly.
But I am not sure if this is the right way, since it does not work when placed in css file.


Stackblitz

For buttons inside of list documentation recommend using mat-action-list. Check it out here https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#action-lists. So if you wrap button in mat-action-list it won't be cut off.

To expand upon @lukap123456 answer, the following code produces the desired result:
<mat-action-list role="list">
  <button type="button" mat-raised-button>Button</button>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 2</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 3</mat-list-item>
</mat-action-list>

